# can i launch an app with some gestures when the phone is in locked state?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios7

I want my app to be launched when i draw some particular gestures or shake my phone in a defined manner the app may be or may not be in running state. please help me if there is a way.

Thanks.

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of a phone being locked if anyone's able to just shake your phone to unlock it...

Comment: i want to make an app which is useful during emergency such when you are under threat or attack. We want to alert our friend about our safety. We want launch app in background and dont want any action the screen as such. all the actions may happen in background.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's actually very interesting!  But I don't think it's really possible to do with an Apple device on its own… Perhaps you could have an external accessory trigger the app, since external accessory communication is one of the background modes supported by iOS7.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: `No`, with a non-jailbroken device this is not possible at all since `apple is restricting the actions` you are allowed to do while your app is performing in background.

Have a look at multitasking and the allowed actions in the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)